# Couldn't find with 'id'=1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It works properly(can show page) before add code

```
# listings_controller.rb
def show
  @lsiting = Listing.find(params[:id])
end
```

> ActiveRecord:RecordNotFound in ListingController#show
>  Couldn't
>   find Listing with 'id'= #

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :categories do
        resources :subcategories
  end

  resources :listings



  root 'categories#index'
  match '/help', to: 'pages#help', via: :get


end
```

---

```
# listings_controller.rb

class ListingsController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @listing = Listing.new
    end


    def create
      @listing = Listing.new(listing_params)

      @listing.save
       redirect_to root_path

    end


    def show
     @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
    end

    private

    def listing_params
      params.require(:listing).permit(:title, :description, :city, :state, :zipcode)
    end

end
```

---

```
<!-- show.html.erb -->


<div class="topbar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="vertical-center">
      rubyslist > jobs > accounting
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <button type="button">reply</button>
    posted
    <h1 class="listing-header"> <%= @listing.title %> </h1>
    <div class="box">
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
    <p> 
  </div>
  <footer>
    <p>post id: </p>
    <p>posted </p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Check you have a listing with id 1 in your database.

Comment: likely your database is empty or doens't contain row with `id=1`. In `rails console`, check `Listing.first.id` and then pass it to `/listing/:id` url instead

Comment: I already checked, Listing.first.
and I did on your reply,
it show 

2.4.1 :004 > Listing.first.id
  Listing Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "listings".* FROM "listings" ORDER BY "listings"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
        from (irb):4

Comment: 2.4.1 :001 > Listing.first
  Listing Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "listings".* FROM "listings" ORDER BY "listings"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => nil

Comment: it means my database is empty ??

Comment: yes. your database is empty.

Comment: Okay, then... how do I create in my database? 
isn't it create ?? before added code,  ~/listing/1 works properly.

Answer (score 0):

As other users are suggesting in the comments, You might not be having a record with `id=1` in your database and in that case `find` method will raise a `ActiveRecord:RecordNotFound`.

Comment: If so, then you can vote for closing the question as off-topic.

Comment: then, How can I add id=1 ? before that code, I can open /listing/1 properly.

Comment: considering you _wrote_ `def create` method, that means you should be able to add listings in your database.

Comment: as you see in my listings_controller.rb, I already wrote 'def create' method. 
so I can create new one.
But I don't know why it doesn't added in my database..
something my server has wrong?

Comment: Validations might be failing. Check for `@listing.errors.full_messages` after `@listing.save`

Comment: or Instead of `@listing.save` use `@listing.save!`

Comment: `save!` will raise an error if not successful.

`save` will return boolean value like true or false.

Comment: I added @listing.error.full_messeages. and then I create a new listing, it just pass to redirect root_path.
It's not wrong I think.

Thank you for all you guys.!!

Comment: yeah. '@listing.save!' makes validation failed.